# Error al recorrer datos de un JSON con Map

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, axios, react-axios

Buen día a todos, tengo un pequeño problema que no he podido resolver y que no se por que se produce.

En la consola me sale lo siguiente: **TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined**

El JSON es este :

```
[{

    "nombre": "Yosip",
    "apellido": "Parrado",
    "Edad": 22


},{

    "nombre": "Andrea",
    "apellido": "Vargas",
    "Edad": 12


},{

    "nombre": "Melisaa",
    "apellido": "Vacca",
    "Edad": 28


}


]
```

Y este es mi componente

```
const ListarFiguras = () =>{


    const[figuras,Setfiguras] = useState({})



    useEffect(()=>{

        ObtenerFiguras();


    },[]);


    function ObtenerFiguras(){

        const url = axios.get("http://localhost/Crud/crud-app/src/Data/Api_M.php");
        url.then(response =>{Setfiguras({isLoaded:true,
            items: response.data,})}).catch(ex =>{

            console.log("Error al obtener los datos"+ex);
        })
    }


    return(
    <Fragment>


        
       {figuras.items.map(items =>(

           <h1>{items.nombre}</h1>
       ))}

        
        </Fragment>
    );

}
```

Mi JSON origina era este, pero lo cambie a la otra estructura para probar pensando que el problema estaba en como estaba construido el JSON. pero no, me da el mismo problema

```
[{"Figura Elefante":"si,si,3,si,si,si,7,si,9,si,si,12,si,14,si,16,17,si,19,20,21,22,si,24,25"},{"Figura Elefante":"si,si,3,si,si,si,7,si,9,si,si,12,si,14,si,16,17,si,19,20,21,22,si,24,25"},{"Figura Tenedor":"si,si,si,si,si,si,7,si,9,si,si,12,si,14,si,16,si,si,si,20,21,si,si,si,25"}]
```

La idea es poder recorrer cada objeto del JSON y poder mostrar su información

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu error radica en que al realizar el primer renderizado la data aún no existe, y por eso obtienes ese error de `undefined`.

Lo que tienes que hacer primero es verificar si existe data:

```
{figuras.items
    ? figuras.items.map((items) => <h1>{items.nombre}</h1>)
    : ""}
```

Así evitas obtener dicho error.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, soy nuevo en esto y no sabia el por que el error, gracias a ti ahora ya se.